# Get parent selector in jQuery On method

Tags: jquery

Is there a way to get **parent selector** (`#dataTable tbody`) inside the block in this code. The `$(this)` here returns the `tr` (child selector).

```
$( "#dataTable tbody" ).on( "click", "tr", function() {
    console.log( $( this ).text() );
});
```

What I'd rather do here is not to using methods like `$(this).closest('#dataTable tbody')` or similar ones, which have me repeat the parent selector id (`#dataTable tbody`).

Comment: `$(this).closest('tbody')` or simply `this.parentElement` resp. `$(this).parent()`. No need to repeat the selector.

Comment: Do you want to get the selector (the string), or the element that was selected (the jQuery object/DOM element)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the delegateTarget property of the jquery event object.

```js
$( "#dataTable tbody" ).on( "click", "tr", function(event) {
    console.log($(event.delegateTarget).text() );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="dataTable">
 <tbody>
   <tr>
     <td>test1</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td>test2</td>
   </tr>
 </tbody>

</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just save the jQuery collection in a variable first, before calling `.on` on it:

```js
const $tbody = $("#dataTable tbody");
$tbody.on("click", "tr", function() {
  console.log($tbody.hasClass('tBodyClass'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id=dataTable>
  <tbody class=tBodyClass>
    <tr>
      <td>td</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```